# unknown command "vftovp" in linux command history [ Is my linux box compromised? ]

Tags: ssh, security, slackware

I have Slackware linux system configured with ssh remote access.

While observing the command history, I discovered that there is one unknown command executed from my linux box "vftovp". I certainly do not remember typing anything like this.

I am not sure if my box has been compromised? Can someone help me understand what this command is and how this command entered into my history.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** It's probably just a typo.

### Long answer

As a quick search shows, [vftovp](http://www.let.rug.nl/alfa/tex/info/web2c/vftovp-invocation.html) could be a tool in the TeX suite to convert a virtual font metric to a virtual property list. So, the original tool would not be something to be concerned of. Two questions are remaining:

1. Who executed this tool on your machine?
2. Is the binary on your system really this TeX tool?

**Who executed this tool on your machine?**

`vf` is a very common typo for `cd`. For me, it is even so common that I have `vf` as an alias to `cd` so I do not have to correct it when mistyped. (BTW, the same goes with `mroe` for `more`. Yes, I'm a bad typist.)

I could imagine that you either typed `vf` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of `cd`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to find a directory to change to. This was then probably expanded to `vftovp`, if this would be the only executable matching this prefix. Or you entered `vf`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and some mechanism in your shell "corrected" your input to `vftovp`. You could easily check this yourself by repeating those inputs.

**Is the binary on your system really this TeX tool?**

For the second question, you could first look if that executable really exists on your system. Using `bash`, I would use this:

```
$ type vftovp
vftovp is /usr/bin/vftovp
```

You should then verify that this executable or script is the original installed from the distribution. Unfortunately I cannot help you with Slackware, but for Debian-based systems, I would use `dpkg -S` to find out the package that installed the file, and then `debsums` to verify the checksum:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/vftovp
texlive-binaries: /usr/bin/vftovp
$ debsums texlive-binaries | grep vftovp
/usr/bin/vftovp                                    OK
/usr/share/man/man1/vftovp.1.gz                    OK
```

*Caveat:* If you really assume that someone compromised your machine, you should not rely on the information given on the machine itself! The binaries to verify checksums, the shell etc. could all be compromised as well. You should mount the filesystem of the assumed compromised machine read-only on another machine, or at least copy the files and test them on another machine.

Comment: I have a lot of software installed on my machine, and `vftovp` is the only command that starts with `vf`. So I second the hypothesis of `vf<Tab>`. Verifying that `vftovp` is genuine is useless because as you say, if the system has been compromised, you can't trust the integrity of the software involved in the verification (starting with the kernel).

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I forgot to mention that. It is the same on my machines.